# Matching lines in two files

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, awk, comm

Let's say I have two files, `file1` and `file2`.

`file1`:

```
passd:xxx
hopla:alli
gnar:gungg
araf:utap
```

`file2`:

```
alli
utap
```

How can i check what lines/words from file2 match file? Indeed I could probably do it with `comm -1 -2 file1 file2` but is it possible to do it with awk?

Comment: tried it with that but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

With awk, you can start with what @jasonwryan suggested [Compare two files...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90489/compare-two-files-with-first-column-and-remove-duplicate-row-from-2nd-file-in-sh)

But modify it to suit your needs. Here is what you can do on the command line, with results:

```
$ awk -F: 'FNR==NR {arr[$0];next} $2 in arr' file2 file1
hopla:alli
araf:utap
```

- you specified `file2` was the list with words to search for
- `file1` was the large text file to search in
- `-F:` specifies delimiter is colon `:`
- `$2` since the field to match is in this case `file1`'s field 2
- when match occurs, default action to print the line, thus you see the two matching lines

### Additional info

- AWK Wiki [ComparingTwoFiles](http://awk.freeshell.org/ComparingTwoFiles) example.

Comment: this prints the whole line , i would need to print just the words that match

Answer (score 0):

This command could help you:

```
cat file1 | awk '{FS=":" print $0}' | xargs grep file2
```

I'm not sure if the diff command could help.  But if it is installed, I would use it: `diff file1 file2`

Comment: Both the `cat` and `grep` are redundant here: Awk reads from files and does pattern matching...

Answer (score 0):

If having issues with grep,

1. Try `dos2unix file1 file2` beforehand to remove any problematic non-Unix formatting that could prevent grep from working
2. as @drewbenn mentioned, `grep -f file2 file1`

You should then successfully see the matching lines:

```
hopla:alli
araf:utap
```